# Set Docker Volume Driver opts via remote api

Tags: azure, docker

Is there a way of setting Docker volume driver opts via the 'POST /containers/create' remote api? I'd like to do something like this:

```
docker run -it -v $(docker volume create -d azurefile -o share=myshare):/data busybox
```

I can create a volume and specify a driver using the json below, but I'm not sure if there's a way of setting the volume driver opts.

```
"HostConfig": {
     "Binds": ["myshare:/data"],
     "VolumeDriver": "azurefile"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem as though this is possible just using /containers/create, but it can be achieved by creating the volume first, and then mounting it to the container.

```
POST /volumes/create
{
  "Name": "myvolume",
  "Driver": "azurefile",
  "DriverOpts": {
    "share": "myshare"
  }
}

POST /containers/create
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "Binds": ["myvolume:/data"],
    "VolumeDriver": "azurefile"
   }
}
```